# Undo a horizontally/vertically flipped bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap

I have succesfully flipped a bitmap horizontally

```
mMirror.preScale(-1.0f, 1.0f);`
```

and vertically

```
mFlip.setScale(-1, 1);
mFlip.postTranslate(bitmap.getWidth(), 0);
```

How do i revert these actions?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:
you can try animations**

```
final ObjectAnimator rotate = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageview,
                "rotationY", 0f, 180f);
        rotate.setDuration(500); /* Duration for flipping the image */
        rotate.setRepeatCount(0);
        rotate.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
rotate.start();
```

in case of undo change rotation values to 180,360

```
final ObjectAnimator rotate = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imagemain,
                "rotationY", 180f, 360f);
        rotate.setDuration(500); /* Duration for flipping the image */
        rotate.setRepeatCount(0);
        rotate.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        rotate.start();
```

**Previous answer:**
You should again call these methods to undo the changes...
or you can take help from this method:

```
public static final int FLIP_VERTICAL = 1;
    public static final int FLIP_HORIZONTAL = 2;

public Bitmap flipImage(Bitmap src, int type) {
        // create new matrix for transformation
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        // if vertical
        if (type == FLIP_VERTICAL) {
            // y = y * -1
            matrix.preScale(1.0f, -1.0f);
        }
        // if horizonal
        else if (type == FLIP_HORIZONTAL) {
            // x = x * -1
            matrix.preScale(-1.0f, 1.0f);
            // unknown type
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        // return transformed image
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(),
                matrix, true);
    }
```

You can flip your bitmap **vertically** or **horizontally** by putting the type in the arguments and restore them to original by again calling that method.

Comment: Calling them again does not work.I cannot figure out why dont they work.

Comment: can you try my method?

Comment: Tried,it still does not reverse it